# Determine if key pressed is in provided array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code similar to this:

```
$("#some-input").keyup(function (event) {
  var availableKeys = [".", ",", ";"];
  var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if (availableKeys.indexOf(key) != -1) {
    alert("Derp");
  }
});
```

However it does not work as I expected. The `event.which`/`fromCharCode` combination works like this properly on digits or letters (capital ones) and this is the correct behaviour since (I presume) event keycodes are different than charset entries.

Is there a workaround other than directly specifying keycodes for comparison (keeping the array of characters is a priority)?

Comment: `event.which` is the best option because it normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`

Comment: do you have problems about buttons like backspace ?

Comment: please check my answer, you will get some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `keypress` instead. Like

```
$("#some-input").bind('keypress', function(e) {
    var availableKeys = [".", ",", ";"];

    if(availableKeys.indexOf( String.fromCharCode( e.which ) ) > -1 ) {
        alert('Derp');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution.  `fromCharCode` or `charCodeAt` are the way to go.

Comment: +1 it's strange how `String.fromCharCode( e.which )` works with `keypress`, but not `keyup`.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as accepted, since I ended up using it, however thank you all for your effort.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - It's not strange, it's on purpose. `.fromCharCode()` is, obviously, expecting a character code, but the keyup and keydown events return a key code, not a character code. This makes sense because it means you can identify which key was pressed even when there are two keys that do the same thing (e.g., the number keys in the main part of the keyboard and the keys in the numeric keypad). The keypress event does return a character code, so that's why it works here.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your array to contain the keycodes of the keys you wish to check for:

```
$("#some-input").keyup(function(event) {
    var availableKeys = [190, 188, 59]; // ".", ",", ";"
    if (availableKeys.indexOf(event.which) != -1) {
        alert("Derp");
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/KtA5B/1/)

[Here's a full list of keycodes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

**Edit**
After a little investigation it appears your method should work, but the implementation of `String.fromCharCode` is flawed - at least for the symbol keys. While pressing `.` returns the correct keyCode of 190, when you run that through fromCharCode you get the string `¾`. Other keys such as `[` and `#` show similar behaviour. I assume this is due to internationalisation, maybe someone else could confirm.

Comment: Well, this will be my last resort, I am aware of this solution (mentioned it in my question). Thanks.

Comment: A little comment to your solution - I am not using `event.which` as a string ;)

Comment: I had the same thoughts as in your edit. However, when I tried using `keypress`, as @jAndy suggested, it returned (properly) `.` or `,`. So there is also a difference in implementation of `keypress` and `keyup`. Tested in Firefox 8, I'll try and see what will it return in a webkit-based browser.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me as though you should try using `charCodeAt` to convert your keys to keycodes at comparison time. eg:

```
alert (".".charCodeAt(0)); // alerts 46
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Answer (score 0):

This very likely is an issue related to the way you are getting the key/char code. Try getting the char/key code like:

```
var code = (event.charCode != 0) ? event.charCode : (event.keyCode != 0 ? event.keyCode : event.which);
var key = String.fromCharCode(code);
```

Can't find any issues in any other part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because you are using `'` as one of the `key` and also as char `separator` in the array so its confusing the program otherwise its working for `.` and `;`.
[**"."** , **"** , **"** , **";"**] . It consider 4 different elements.
use belwo code:

```
$("#some-input").keypress(function (event) {
 var availableKeys = ",.;";
  var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
  if (availableKeys.indexOf(key) != -1) {
    alert("Derp");
  }
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/AVcrw/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org):

```
$("#some-input").bind('keypress', function(event) {
        var aKeys = [13, 32];

        if ( _.contains(aKeys, event.which) ) {
            console.log("char :"  + event.which);
        }
});
```